Custom token JWT Auth with Appwrite and Firebase Auth on Flutter issue
So I have my primary authentication on appwrite for my Flutter app. I now need to use some of firebase's services and would like to create a custom token auth system. I authenticate the user on appwrite and return a jwt in the right format generated by their SDK. Then, I pass it to firebase and for some reason, I get this error:
Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/flutter (20524): Error signing in: [firebase_auth/unknown] An internal error has occurred. [ MISSING_IDENTIFIER
   getcustomtoken() async {
     final token = await account.createJWT();
     String customToken = token.jwt;
     signInWithCustomToken(customToken);
  }

Future<void> signInWithCustomToken(String customToken) async {

try {
UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCustomToken(customToken);
print("User signed in: ${userCredential.user!.uid}");
final like = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

} catch (e) {
print("Error signing in: $e");
}
}


I tried checking the token with a JWT token checker and the data in payload was correct.
I'd appreciate the help! Thanks.
